# Wifi hard blocked

Tags: wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on my Lenovo-G50-30 laptop, replacing Windows 8. '*Enable wifi*' is greyed out. Typing `rfkill list all` in the terminal tells me that

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
and
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

So the problem is presumably that `ideapad_wlan` is hard blocked. '`sudo rfkill unblock all`' doesn't change this. There seems to be no switch on the laptop itself, nor are any of the F keys relevant.

How do I enable WiFi?

Comment: Have you tried Fn + F7?

Comment: "hard blocked" means what it says: -hardware- is blocking your wifi. So ... either you have a slider on the side of your notebook or you have a keyboard combination (like Fn F7 Mitch suggested) or you have a BIOS setting where wifi is disabled.  As far as I know that are probably all the options. So if the 1st 2 are checked you could check your BIOS for a block ;)

Comment: I found configuration by pressing esc as soon as the computer started turning on. All wireless devices were already enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this can be fixed by blacklisting the ideapad_laptop module with `echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf` and rebooting
If it doesn't work the blacklist can be removed with `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf`
There is a fix being worked on and addition models being added and some models are fixed in the Utopic 3.16.0-30 kernel

Dmitry Tunin has made a kernel with the fix if you want to try it, a link from the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1397021/comments/6

Comment: This made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Can you add the results of `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name` as I might be able to modify the source code

Comment: `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name` gives `80G0`

Comment: I should also add that the [documentation](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g40_g50_z40_z50_ug_english.pdf) (for use with windows 8) includes turning off airplane mode via f7. Pressing f7 or fn+f7 gives no response and doesn't change anything. Bluetooth is also hard blocked, if that is relevant.

Comment: Airplane mode is off I have confirmed, and Bluetooth is also hard blocked. On settings-->network, it is possible to drag the bluetooth slider into the 'on' position, but impossible to drag the wireless slider into the 'on' position (it just snaps back).

Comment: I believe your problem is related to issues with the Yoga series http://iseborn.eu/2014/07/21/activating-wifi-in-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2/ but the ideapad_laptop.c needs to be changed to include your model

Comment: Thanks I will have a go at that.  For Dmitry Tunin's fix, I can download the files from dropbox - how do I use them? (I'm new to ubuntu)

Comment: Also I don't understand how to change ideapad_laptop.c

Comment: Actually, your original suggestion worked!  I'm not sure why it didn't work before; maybe I didn't quite follow the instructions properly, but I now have wifi even after rebooting :)  Thank you!

Comment: If you have issues with the FN combos or backlighting, let me know and I will modify the code for you.

Comment: I did have a backlight issues actually but managed to solve it with google. My next problem is that [there is no touchpad scrolling (and no opting to turn it on/off in settings)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/588226/touchpad-scrolling-unavailable).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my x200 and none of these solutions worked. Turns out I had forgotten to reconnect my CMOS battery and once reconnected it worked. I don't know if this was the cause or if I knocked something accidentally and it started working but if anyone is in a similar situation, it's worth a try.