# Touchpad scrolling unavailable

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on my Lenovo-G50-30 laptop, replacing Windows 8.
Systems settings --> Mouse & touchpad has no options beyond primary button, double-click and pointer-speed. How do I enable touchpad scrolling?

Comment: What is your current kernel verion `uname -a`

Comment: Linux j-Lenovo-G50-30 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu S MP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Ubuntu Software Center and install Pointing devices.

Comment: Done that. It has 'use wheel emulation' where you can set the button from 1, 2, 3 or 4. 1 is left click, 3 is right click, 2 and 4 don't seem to do anything. Right click and scroll will do for now, but I would prefer two-finger, or edge-of-touchpad scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here: http://iseborn.eu/2014/07/21/activating-wifi-in-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2/ to make a new module, but I don't want you to use the ideapad_laptop.c from that site, use https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6ltq7uy5sv9cww/ideapad_laptop.c?dl=0 instead

And if the `make install` command gives permission errors use `sudo make install`

Touchpad should return to normal after `make install` or `sudo make install` and with any luck your wifi should be unaffected and you can remove the blacklist file with `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf`