# Lenovo G580 Atheros AR9485 Not Working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lenovo, atheros, wifi-hardware-switch

I am facing a BIG problem regarding **Wi-Fi** in Ubuntu 14.0.4. System is Lenovo G580.

I have read almost 50+ threads related to this problem but none of them are working for me.

**Details**:-
Commands that I have executed and their results are given as follows:-

**Command:-** lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3979]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3218]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

**Command:-**  rfkill list all

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

**Command**:- lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2e2 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 17ef:6042 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Command**:- lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ath9k                 147456  0 
ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              458752  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              708608  1 ath9k
cfg80211              524288  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
rfcomm                 69632  0 
bnep                   20480  2 
kvm_intel             151552  0 
kvm                   479232  1 kvm_intel
bluetooth             491520  10 bnep,rfcomm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
aesni_intel           172032  0 
snd_hda_intel          32768  3 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
arc4                   16384  2 
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1 
serio_raw              16384  0 
joydev                 20480  0 
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         53248  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0 
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    86016  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
i915                 1048576  3 
lpc_ich                24576  0 
shpchp                 40960  0 
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915
parport_pc             32768  0 
mei_me                 20480  0 
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
ppdev                  20480  0 
drm                   344064  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
ideapad_laptop         20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  20480  1 i915
mac_hid                16384  0 
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0 
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
ahci                   36864  4 
psmouse               114688  0 
alx                    36864  0 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mdio                   16384  1 alx
```

**Command**:- iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**Command**:- iwlist chan

```
wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
   `enter code here`       Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
lo        no frequency information.
```

**Command**:-  sudo iwlist scan

```
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

**Command**:- uname -rv

```
3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015
```

**Command**:- cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

In the right corner of the Unity top-panel, Connection tab displays "Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch".

I have also tried to repair this problem via Troubleshooter in Windows 10 but this also led nowhere. It shows Wi-Fi connectivity is disabled.

I hope you guys will make my new year happy by solving this problem. :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to run `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop && sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: Can you add the output of 'uname -rv'?

Comment: @Pilot6: Bro I have run your command but problem exist.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste:- I have added output of your command in question

Comment: Sry, a typo `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @Pilot6: Bro see output of your command in question

Comment: Did you try the first command? Did it fix the wifi? If not you may need to reset bios to default.

Comment: @Pilot6:- Thanks for your prompt reply. I have run your first command but Problem is still exist. BIOS is already in its default mode.

Comment: You're on Linux 3.19. Why don't you upgrade to a newer version to see if that fixes it? Run 'sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless disabled by hardware switch on an Asus X550V](http://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-an-asus-x550v)

Comment: @David Foerster:- Brother our manufacturers are different. Our problem was same but solutions are different in Asus and Lenovo. I have read many threads as I mentioned in my question.  Your solution won't work in my case.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste: Brother I have run your command but I got some error message. I am digging into it.

Comment: @RaviHirani: The wireless adapter in the linked question is AR9485. Does that ring any bells? Its manufacturer Atheros was acquired by Qualcomm recently, hence why the manufacturer is either labelled "Atheros" (in the linked question) or "Qualcomm Atheros" (in your case). Which answers/instructions did you try to run? That knowledge would help greatly to determine a possible solution for you.

Comment: @David Foerster:  You need to google it. Even both manufacturers are using the same network adaptor like Aethros AR9485 and both have the same problem such as "hardblocked : yes" then  the  solutions are different for both manufacturers. that's why people write manufacturer name also.  You can crosscheck  it. and I had tried your suggested solution and 50+ others. In your solution asus_nb_wmi file there. while there is no such file in lenovo. try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Function (Fn) key combo on your keyboard to turn on WLAN.
(Find the Fn key and the key with a colored WiFi antenna and then press and hold the Fn key and then press the colored WiFi antenna button.)

May this solve it? Or just make sure that you tried even this one.

Comment: Yes. I had tried that one also.

Answer (score -1):

Since the normal methods have failed to work and even though I have found this to work only with Toshiba laptops.

Power down the laptop
Remove battery and power cord
Press and hold power button for 30 seconds

Replace battery, insert power cord, and boot it up

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. This method does not work for lenovo laptops.

Comment: Actually, try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/587760/300665) if you haven't yet.  I didn't think the G580 was affected but it could be.  My G710 doesn't have that issue