# intel WIFI AC 9560 don't work in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

I don't know how to solve the problem , I'm fresh in linux and have googling whole night didn't get any clue.

the wifi info detail in this link

https://pastebin.com/pJh1HyV6

```
~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.328734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.c0e03d94.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.365312] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    3.419871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 18:1d:ea:72:e8:ae
[    3.490239] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.491152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: @mikewhatever  maybe different,

Comment: May be this could help [Wifi hard blocked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587743/wifi-hard-blocked). Situation seems to be somewhat similar.

Answer (score 2):

According to the rfkill report, your WiFi is working properly, it is just hardblocked.

Find what is hardblocking the wifi. (Probably a hardware switch you might need to toggle).