# Can't compile rtl8821ce wifi driver on Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, lubuntu, make, realtek-wireless

I'm trying to get Linux working with my Lenovo Yoga 530-14ARR laptop. It has a wireless Realtek "rtl8821ce" card, which is not recognized out of the box by my brand new Lubuntu 18.10 install (I tried other lightweight distros before, without success). According to [this question's top answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce), compiling [this](https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce) and `modprobe` the resulting module should do the trick.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to compile on my machine:

```
liloboot@lubuntu:~/rtl8821ce$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-10-generic/build M=/home/liloboot/rtl8821ce  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-10-generic'
Makefile:982: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/liloboot/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
    /home/liloboot/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: error: initialization of ‘u16 (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *, void *, u16 (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *))’ {aka ‘short unsigned int (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *, void *, short unsigned int (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *))’} from incompatible pointer type ‘u16 (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *, struct net_device *, u16 (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *))’ {aka ‘short unsigned int (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *, struct net_device *, short unsigned int (*)(struct net_device *, struct sk_buff *))’} [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/liloboot/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: note: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:327: /home/liloboot/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1546: _module_/home/liloboot/rtl8821ce] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-10-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1902: modules] Error 2
```

EDIT: Following chili555's comment, I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04/1070645#1070645). It finally worked but I had several problems that I want to point out in an answer. See below.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 uses a newer kernel version than that contemplated in the answer you quoted above. I suggest that you try this instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04/1070645#1070645 It 'makes' for me in 18.10, albeit with a few possibly harmless warnngs. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I posted an answer with some complements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems and solutions when following the steps of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04/1070645#1070645):

- Coming from a Windows PC, all script files where in a wrong format, resulting in a 'no such file or directory' error when trying to `sudo ./dkms-install.sh`. I had to `dos2unix` all of them.
- I had to manually `sudo`-run some of the `dkms` commands in `dkms-install.sh` because `sudo ./dkms-install.sh` was reporting errors that I finally interpreted as a lack of privileges. Don't know why.

> sudo dkms build -m rtl8821ce -v v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108
>
> sudo dkms install -m rtl8821ce -v v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108

- Then I rebooted and  `ip a` showed the new `wlp1s0` network interface. But I was not out of the woods yet.
- The wifi module was still hard-blocked, as shown by the outputs of `nmcli radio` and `rfkill list`. I had to add an entry to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as explained in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380586/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-wifi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked-yes): append `blacklist ideapad_laptop` at the end of the file, then reboot.

And the wifi module is now working properly.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it's working.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks again! 15 years without Linux and the first thing I had to do when coming back was messing with a wireless connection problem... I see that manufacturers still have a long way to go... You really have to want it on some configurations.