# Wi-fi not enable on Lenovo thinkpad L420 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad

I am new to Ubuntu. I tried installing `Ubuntu 20.04` on my `Lenovo L420` laptop, WiFi is not enabled. I checked WiFi adapter it is already enabled. Even `Bluetooth` is working.

After I installed `Ubuntu 20.04` airplane mode is automatically enabled. Then I am not able to disable airplane mode.

I used this command to disable airplane mode `sudo rfkill unblock all`.

I checked in additional drivers list it is showing `No additional drivers available`.

[image]

I am new here please help me to solve this issue.

> Note: In this same laptop I installed same `Ubuntu 20.04` that time WiFi was working.

Comment: What does `rfkill list` return?

Comment: Also, try to toggle the wireless radio switch. It should be located on the right side of the laptop near the front.

Comment: @mchid yes it is enabled already. `rfkill list` shows this one https://ibb.co/0KYm48V

Comment: Hard block refers to your hardware switch.

Comment: @mchid: Am using Lenovo L420 thinkpad laptop. I enabled `wi-fi` toggle switch.

Comment: @mchid please check this image I enabled wifi toggle https://ibb.co/SspyDrV

Comment: What does `lsmod | grep pad` return? Also, it's better to just paste the output into a reply or add it to the question as opposed to a screenshot.

Comment: If it returns `ideapad_laptop` please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/487210/167115)

Comment: If that command works, then refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/484376/167115) to make the change permanent by blacklisting the module. Also, please let me know if it works and I will mark this question as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @mchid: `lsmod | grep pad` returns this https://ibb.co/7J0jHyz